# Conflict about my authorship with former supervisor

Tags: authorship, supervision, conflict-of-interest, research-misconduct

For four years I worked in the laboratory of my former supervisor. For unknown reasons, she always mistreated me - I had the smallest salary in the laboratory (and when I once asked her why, she cut my bonuses and then completely canceled them). She often lied to me about laboratory projects (and we had less than 10 people in our lab so it was hard not to notice), never taught me anything ("I have no time for you"), did not invite me to go to conferences, etc.  When I asked her questions on this topic, she stopped giving me any work for a while. Apparently to teach me obedience.

However, I worked hard.  I did a lot of wet biology for her projects and advised her on techniques that could be used to get the results she was interested in. But I never received scientific publications.  Everything I did was never right or enough for her to put me on the list of contributors.

Now I have moved on to another laboratory, and I no longer depend on her. And I have proof that I have done work for several of her published and forthcoming articles.

For example:

1. Emails and excel files on drosophila mutant longevity studies with statistical analysis done by me.  I had to go to work on weekends for three months to get this analysis done.  The reason why myself and another researcher working on this project (who was also on strained terms with her) were not included: "This work was assigned to another researcher as his doctoral dissertation."
2. A lab journal with documented "wet" studies, an email and an edited article on working with bacteria by me with a draft version that was provided to me by her. I have rewritten it fully. Reason why I was not included: "It's not a valuable addition."
3. Excel file and e-mails related to the ways we could do a scientific experiment on bacteria.  One of the proposed options was used in a published article, and I also ordered the reagents for it.  The reason why I was not included: "You were not around when we got this bacterium (during the expedition where they did not take me), so we have the right not to include you."

The two papers I did myself, my bachelor's and master's theses, were my only publications in the form of patent documents.  I was told to be grateful that I was allowed to use them, even though I did them from start to finish on my own.  For four years of research, this is not much, and since I want to apply for a PhD, this is not a good background for me.

Therefore, I have a question - does it make sense to fight for my authorship in these cases? Or is it better to forget about these four years as a nightmare, not seek justice and move on, because I will lose more reputation than I could gain?

Comment: related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/183939/is-it-ethical-to-deny-someone-co-authorship-who-had-not-had-the-chance-to-contri

Comment: Which of these are already published/forthcoming and which are still pre-submission? The cost-benefit analysis changes…

Comment: 1) Partly published, but it is a long study with future articles on this subject 2) is in pre-submission 3) published